# Lost the root privilege after try to add the user to a group

Tags: grub2, permissions, sudo, users, root

My user lost root privilege after try to add the user to a group. It's looks like the "usermod xxxx --groups ..." change the from the root group to the new one, it's a mistake but the thing is my user lost all root privilege and as you know, ubuntu un the instalation process ask to create an user (the uniqueone I have) with root privilege but never ask (if I'm not wrong) to give an password to root user.

How can I fix this? how can I recover root capacity?

Yesterday I tried to boot in "save mode" but I couldn't, I have just ubuntu installed in my PC and when I tried to get the grub windows (whit ESC) it just show a console with "GRUB>" and some instructions that I`ve never seen before and don't understand.

I don't know what to ...

Answer (score 0):

From boot meny, select `recovery mode` (ususally second from top), wait for the boot-up till you are presented with the `Recovery Menu`. Select the `root` option from the menu and you will drop in the root shell.

Re-mount the file system as read-write

```
 mount -o rw,remount /
```

Add your user to sudo group

```
adduser username sudo
```

And, exit.

```
exit
```

You will go back to the `Recovery Menu`. Select `resume` option for normal boot. You will be able to use `sudo` again.